# How to deal with odata service created with 1000 rows of hana table in SAP hana XS app

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana

I have a table of 1000 rows in Hana.

Then I created an odata service on that table using xsodata service to expose the data as odata.(working fine)

Now I want to use this on my XS app as list.

The problem is as there is 1000 rows the list is not loading all the data, it's showing the first record and the busy indicator showing 1/1000 more.

Error on console: getTimer is not a function. ( this part I did not get)

Now my question is how to get all the data(1000 rows) on the list, say loading 10 at first, and then I scroll down to show more.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good for you: Lazy loading is a built-in feature of SAPUI5 :)

Just add some extra properties to your list

```
<List id="contractList"
    growing="true"
    growingScrollToLoad="true"
    growingThreshold="10"
    items="{MyItems}">

    <StandardListItem title="{MyTitle}" description="{MyDescription}" press="onPress" />

</List>
```

The `growing` property enables (or disables) the lazy loading.
The `growingScrollToLoad` enables loading via scrolling. If false, there is a button to load more items. The `growingThreshold` defines how many items will be fetched each time.

See the API for more information: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html

---

However this will not solve your other problem (`getTimer is not a function`). You should try to solve that before implementing lazy loading.

Comment: I had `growing` property in my code, I also think `getTimer` is my main issue. Any Way thanks for your reply..

Comment: As I said, your real problem is your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that for models containing more than 100 entries, you may need to set the limit using sap.ui.model.Model.setSizeLimit() to allow more than the 100 entries to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Once your oModel is loaded with data add another code as below

oModel.setSizeLimit(500)